# How do I craft a regular expression to exclude strings with parentheses

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have the following SDDL:

```
O:BAG:BAD:(A;;CCDCLCSWRP;;;BA)(A;;CCDCSW;;;WD)(A;;CCDCLCSWRP;;;S-1-5-32-562)(A;;CCDCLCSWRP;;;LU)(A;;CCLCRP;;;S-1-5-21-4217728705-3687557540-3107027809-1003)
```

Unfortunately I keep getting this:

```
(A;;CCDCLCSWRP;;;BA)(A;;CCDCSW;;;WD)
```

And what I want is just `(A;;CCDCSW;;;WD)`.

My regex is: `(\(A;.+;WD\))` : find "`(A;`" some characters ending in "`;WD)`"

I've tried making the match lazy and I've tried excluding the "`)(`" pair of characters based on a search of the stackoverflow regex tag looking for examples where others have answered similar questions.

I'm really confused why the exclusion of the parens isn't working:

`(\(A;.+[^\(\)]*.+;WD\))` : find "`(A;`" followed by some characters where none of them are "`)(`'' followed by other characters ending in "`;WD)`"

And this was my guess at using negative look around:

```
(\(A;.+^((?!\)\().).+;WD\))
```

which didn't match anything.

I'm also doing this in PowerShell v3.0 with the following code:

```
$RegExPattern = [regex]"(\($ACE_Type;.*;$ACE_SID\))+?"
if ($SDDL -match $RegExPattern) {
    $MatchingACE = $Matches[0]
```

Where in this instance `$ACE_Type = "A"` and `$ACE_SID = "WD"`.

Comment: what output do you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had the solution with your second regex pattern.  The problem was that you included too many `.` wildcards.  This should be all you need:

`A;[^()]+;WD`

And of course if you just want to capture the string in between `A;` and `;WD`:

`A;([^()]+);WD`

Then just replace with `\1`.

Comment: It's interesting that you don't have to escape the parens inside the specified set of characters. I did try it with and without escape characters. And I did feel when I was describing my regex that I had too many 'match any characters'. So in this answer the [^()]+ means match any one or more characters that aren't parenthesis. I thought it only meant "don't match these characters" and wasn't inclusive of the rest. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yep, as a general rule, the square brackets will treat special regex characters either as literals (eg. `[.]` matches a literal ".") or as different special characters (eg. `[^]` starts character negation rather than matches the beginning of the string).  There are exceptions however, such as the escape backslash "\" and many of the character classes such as `\w`.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified this a lot and then added lookarounds so that you only matched the intended string (in between `A;...;WD`).  This looks behind for `A;`, then matches 1+ non-parenthesis characters, while looking ahead for `;WD`.

```
(?<=A;)[^()]+(?=;WD)
```

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/bP3aB6)